# SimpLess can't import less (file not found)

Tags: import, path, compiler-errors, less

I have the following file structure:

```
<project folder>
---/Project
------/static
---------/app/numbers/style1.less
---------/less/colors.less
```

style1.less has the following import:

```
@import url("../../less/colors");
```

and it works fine with less.js

However, when I want to precompile the css with SimpLESS, the import path is not found.
For the above mentioned import statement SimpLESS starts looking for file:

> /Project/static/app/number/less/colors.less.less

I've tried setting various paths, but nothing works so far.
The only solution I see at this point is to put all the .less files into one folder, however I still hope that there is a solution that doesn't require changing the file structure.

Would be grateful for any suggestions.

**Update:**
It's not actually an answer to my question, so I'll just add it here.
The only workaround for me was to use [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) or [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/) rather than SimpLESS.
Although, I haven't tried [AutoLESS](https://github.com/jgonera/autoless) yet, so this could be another option.

Comment: Tried precompiling those files with Web Essentials and it worked. Now I'm totally confused why it doesn't work with SimpLESS

Comment: Have you tried specifying the file with the extension and without the url()?  For example, the canonical form of the import statement is `@import "../../less/colors.less"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. SimpLESS then starts looking for file /Project/static/app/number/less/colors.less.less

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem on Windows.  What platform are you on?  Could you post actual files which show a simplified test case?

Comment: Also, it's not an answer to this specific question but you can possibly workaround the problem by using another solution than SimpLESS.  For example, AutoLESS is another command-line file watcher for LESS - https://github.com/jgonera/autoless. A benefit of AutoLESS is that it is based on LESS 1.3.3, which is higher than SimpLESS's 1.3.0.  In addition, it simply downloads the LESS 1.3.3 library which should be easy to replace with any newer version. A second option is to use the canonical lessc compiler along with a file watcher utility which will run it whenever they detect a change.

Comment: I'm running Win7 x64, there's nothing specific to the files: just some css. I've moved from SimpLESS to Web Essentials for VS2012 and Crunch: both of these work just fine.
However, still confused, why SimpLESS failed...